# Como mostrar los productos creados por el usuario?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Necesito poder mostrar los productos que ha creado el usuario que se encuentra logueado, para ello he hecho esta función que genera un ShortCode:

```
function productosUsuario() {
    global $current_user, $user_login;

    if ($user_login) {
        
        $product = wc_get_product( '1149' );
        $html = '<section id="my-products">
            <div class="item">
                <figure>'. $product->get_image() .'</figure>
                <div class="info">
                    <span class="sku">'. $product->get_sku() .'</span>
                    <h2 class="name">'. $product->get_name() .'</h2>
                    <span class="visits">3 Visits | 1 Contact</span>
                </div>
                <div class="price">
                    <h2>us$'. $product->get_price() .'</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="quality">
                    <span class="number">85%</span>
                    <label>Standar Quality</label>
                </div>
                <div class="actions">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/edit-product/?product_id='. 
                        $product->get_id() .'">Edit Product</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../product/'. 
                            $product->get_slug() . 
                            '">View you Product</a></li>
                        <li>Pause</li>
                        <li><a href="/frequent-questions/">I need Help!</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>';

        echo $html;
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'productosUsuario', 'productosUsuario' );
```

La función solo muestra un producto específico pero yo necesito que muestre los productos del usuario que está logueado, ¿cómo hago ese filtro y/o condición?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el id del usuario actual usamos [`get_current_user_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/):

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
```

Da como resultado un `(int)` que es `0` si no hay usuario logeado, no hace falta acceder a la global.

Para obtener la lista de productos creados por un usuario en particular usamos [`wc_get_products`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-product-functions.html#function_wc_get_products), pasándole el `user_id` como `author`:

```
$products = wc_get_products([
  'status'    => 'publish',
  'limit'     => -1,
  'author'    => $user_id
]);
```

Dentro de un shortcode, definimos algunos defaults como para limitar el número de productos o elegir el author por id, chequeamos que la función de woocommerce esté disponible, buffereamos el output ( dentro de un theme o plugin podes usar get template parts ahí con el html y dar la posibilidad de overrides ), todo junto queda mas o menos así:

```php
add_shortcode('productosUsuario', 'productsbyuser_shortcode_query');
function productsbyuser_shortcode_query( $atts = [], $content = null, $tag )
{
  $output = '';
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
  // atts defaults
  $atts = shortcode_atts(
    [
      'user_id' => $user_id,
      'limit' => -1,
    ], $atts, $tag
  );

  if ( 0 === $atts['user_id'] ) {
    $output = 'No user ID';
    return $output;
  }

  if ( ! function_exists( 'wc_get_products' ) ) {
    $output = 'No Woo active';
    return $output;
  }

  $products = wc_get_products([
    'status'    => 'publish',
    'limit'     => $atts['limit'],
    'author'    => $atts['user_id']
  ]);

  if ( ! empty( $products ) ) {
    ob_start(); ?>
    <section id="my-products">
      <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
        <div class="item">
          <figure><?php echo $product->get_image() ?></figure>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="sku"><?php echo $product->get_sku();?></span>
            <h2 class="name"><?php echo $product->get_name(); ?></h2>
            <span class="visits">3 Visits | 1 Contact</span>
          </div>
          <div class="price">
            <h2>us$<?php echo $product->get_price(); ?></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="quality">
            <span class="number">85%</span>
            <label>Standar Quality</label>
          </div>
          <div class="actions">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="<?php
              echo esc_url( get_edit_post_link( $product->get_id() ) ); 
              ?>">Edit Product</a></li>
              <li><a href="<?php
              echo esc_url( $product->get_permalink() );
              ?>">View you Product</a></li>
              <li>Pause</li>
              <li><a href="<?php
              echo esc_url( get_permalink(
                get_page_by_path( 'frequent-questions') )
              );
              ?>">I need Help!</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </section>
    <?php
    $output = ob_get_clean();
  } else {
    $output = 'No products';
  }
  return html_entity_decode($output);
}
```